# Store const data directly in the program code or in JSON?

Tags: json

I’m working on my project about regular expressions. I want to display some help info like this: [example of displaying info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNfF7.png).

A have a lot of such hints. So the question: should i hardcode it directly inside program code? Or it will be better to store it inside JSON and parse it at the start of my app?

I found some benefits of storing data inside JSON. But it makes me always store JSON with my app. It it worth it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends on the type of info you are storing. If you have a lot of info of similar type, e.g. a selection of books:

```
{
  "name": "Alice in The Wonderland",
  "price": "30",
  "ID": 123456789,
  "genres": {
    "adventure": true,
    "romance": false,
    "horror": false,
    "scifi": false,
    "fiction": true
  }
}
```

Then I would say I'd recommend using JSON. It's easy to add new instances of data or edit existing ones. I'm using this to store data about stuff selling on a one of my websites (anyobjects.ru)

But in this case I would say storing const data in your code would be more comfortable, since the chance that it's going to be changed is very low & you wont have to convert data from JSON.

In case you decide to use JSON here is a way to decode it in C#:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;

class ReadJsonFile
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(@"./data.json");
        var data= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(text);
        return data
    }
}
```